# How are output digits handled differently by KnitR in chunks and inline code?

Tags: r, knitr

I am confused about how KnitR handles the `digits` of output differently in chunks and in inline code with `\Sexpr{}`. Generally, I want them to be handled the same. This should not pose any problem once I understand how to set the options for both types of output, which I have not found in the manual. Please see the MWE below.

```
\documentclass[12pt, english, oneside]{amsart}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
options(digits=2)
pi
@
\Sexpr{pi}
\end{document}
```

In case you don't feel like compiling this, the chunk prints 3.1 whereas the `\Sexpr` prints 3.14.

Answer (score 1):

According to `?options`:

```
 ‘digits’: controls the number of digits to print when printing
      numeric values.  It is a suggestion only.  Valid values are
      1...22 with default 7.  See the note in ‘print.default’ about
      values greater than 15.
```

Note in particular **It is a suggestion only**. But in `knitr`, the inline numbers are `round()`ed according to `getOption('digits')` by default.